# REST API - Connection Difficulties

Tags: javascript, sql-server, rest, tedious, node-mssql

I'm trying to make a rest API that can connect to my sql Server database, but I'm getting this error:

ConnectionError: Connection is closed
at Request._query( ...)
at Request.query(..)
Code: 'ECONNCLOSED'

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express'); // Web Framework
var app = express();
var sql = require('mssql'); // MS Sql Server client

// Connection string parameters.
var sqlConfig = {
    user: 'UserName',
    password: 'mot de passe',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'DatabaseName',
    "enableArithAbort": true
}

// Start server and listen on http://localhost:8081/
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});

app.get('/customers', function (req, res) {
   sql.connect(sqlConfig, function () {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('select * from Sales.Customer', function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset)); // Result in JSON format
        });
             sql.close();
    });
})
```

Comment: I don't see where you're opening a connection.  See https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/getting-started.html for a "Hello World" example.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was following this example: https://medium.com/voobans-tech-stories/how-to-quickly-create-a-simple-rest-api-for-sql-server-database-7ddb595f751a I'm not sure if they were even using tedious or not

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm establishing a connection in app.get() where it says sql.connection()

Comment: Apparently not.